# Add self-closing tags using juicePreserveTags options within an MJML Gulp task

Tags: gulp, html-email, mjml

I'm using a clone of the git Repo: https://github.com/jpagano/mjml-starter-base

How can I add the configuration options found here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/mjmlio/mjml/1528/467101657

```
config.juicePreserveTags='{"imgTag": { "start": "<img", "end": "/>" }, "brTag": { "start": "<br", "end": "/>" }}'
```

I have tried that:

```
export function buildMjml() {
  const options = {
    beautify: true,
    minify: false,
    keepComments: false,
    juicePreserveTags: '{"imgTag": { "start": "<img", "end": "/>" }, "brTag": { "start": "<br", "end": "/>" }}',
  };

  return gulp.src(PATHS.mjml.src).pipe(mjmlGulp(mjml, options)).pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist));
}
```

But this don't add the closing tags to the image and br tags

Comment: It looks like a command line format: https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/blob/master/packages/mjml-cli/README.md#preserve-specific-tags-when-using-inline-mj-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the options should be set as a valid js object.

```
juicePreserveTags: {
  imgTag: { "start": "<img", "end": "/>" }, 
  brTag: { "start": "<br", "end": "/>" }
},
```